# Web Application listening to ActiveX component events in Console Application

Tags: c#, events, visual-studio-2005, activex, .net-2.0

I have this huge issue and I can't get the end of it.

I have created an ActiveX dll component. It is used in Console Application which creates an instance of it and runs in tray. Here is the code:

```
class Program
{
    public static string MSG;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);


    static NotifyIcon tray = new NotifyIcon();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Title = "ActiveXConsole";
        Program program = new Program();

        IntPtr hWnd = FindWindow(null, "ActiveXConsole"); 

        if (hWnd != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            ShowWindow(hWnd, 0); 
        }


        tray.Icon = new Icon("App.ico");
        tray.Visible = true;
        tray.Text = "ActiveXConsole";
        tray.ShowBalloonTip(3000, "ActiveXConsole", "ActiveXConsole working...", ToolTipIcon.None);

        program.ActivateActiveX();

    }



    public void ActivateActiveX()
    {
        ActiveXdll.Class1 activex = new ActiveXdll.Class1();
        activex.OnMessage += new EventHandler<NewMessageArgs>(ProcessMessage);
        //this activates the StartListen method that is listening for a UDP message.
        //the event is created in it
        activex.StartListen();
    }


    public void ProcessMessage(object sender, NewMessageArgs args)
    {

        IntPtr hWnd = FindWindow(null, "ActiveXConsole");
        MSG = args.Message;

        tray.ShowBalloonTip(3000, "ActiveXConsole", "UDP Message has arrived", ToolTipIcon.None);

    }

}
```

}

The DLL actually receives UDP string on some port and 'translates' it into event, which is handled in the console application, as seen in the code above.

This works well so far, but I got stacked. Now I need to make web application that listens to these events. The reason I can't use the DLL directly in the web application, is that if the tab that activates it is opened more than once (thus will activate it more than once), the UDP socket listener will create some conflict because no more than one socket can be opened on the same port in the same time.

I know there is a way to do this since I've seen it in other software, but how? What is the best way to do it? Basically the console application creates instance of the ActiveX DLL and the events that are raised there are listened by a web application which does something when triggered.

We are using .NET 2.0 framework, company policy. Don't ask me why we aren't migrating to something newer.

Comment: I don't know why in the world you would use ActiveX for this.

Comment: Not my choice, I was ordered to do so. I wanted to make it with Web Service or any other way since ActiveX is dying, but if they tell you that you HAVE to do it that way, well...

Answer (score 0):

Try taking your console application and hosting a WCF service in it. The web application can then poll the service to ask whether there's been an event or not.

Comment: We are using Visual Studio 2005 with .NET 2.0. As far as I know, WCF service is supported from .NET 3.0 and above. (and don't ask why we are so 'old-fashioned', no one asks me). Correct me if i'm wrong, or if not, any other idea?

Comment: @Paul: do you think this might have been relevant information? .NET 2.0 is _so_ limited compared to later releases, that you will simply not get useful answers unless you admit that you're still using it.

Comment: .NET 3.5 is simply .NET 2.0 with some additional assemblies. You should be able to use it in the same environments where you use .NET 2.0 (unless maybe you have to support Windows Server 2000). There are few good reasons to stick with .NET 2.0.

Comment: so you are saying that i can try and make WCF, no matter we use 2.0 framework? Thanks, i will try to do that way.

Comment: I'm saying you'll have to install .NET 3.5. But .NET 3.5 is just .NET 2.0 Service Pack 2 plus some extra assemblies. You should be able to convince people that this is a safe combination. Note that I am **not** suggesting an upgrade to .NET 4.0, 4.5, or 4.5.1. Those involve a new version of the CLR and _do_ require some thought before upgrading. But .NET 3.5 is almost a no brainer - it's just a service pack as far as your existing .NET 2.0 code is concerned, but you can then use the extra assemblies, including those for WCF.